# Using getopt in unix shell

Tags: linux, unix, shell

I have to use a Unix script to pass arguments:

```
./Script.sh -c "abc" -d "def" -k "abc -d -c"
```

where the argument for:

- `-c` = "abc"
- `-d` = "def"
- `-k` = "abc -d -c"

How can I handle options in a Uunix shell script?

Comment: What do you see when you try `getopt -T; echo $?`?

Answer (score 2):

Here is some option handling using `getopts`:

```
#   -F          Final version (do not append date to version)
#   -s suffix   Add '-suffix' after version number
#   -V          Print version and exit
#   -h          Print help and exit
#   -j jdcfile  JDC file for project - required
#   -q          Quiet operation
#   -v          Verbose operation

arg0=$(basename $0 .sh)

usage()
{
    echo "Usage: $arg0 [-hqvFV] [-s suffix] -j jdcfile file.msd" 1>&2
    exit 1
}

error()
{
    echo "$0: $*" 1>&2
    exit 1
}

Fflag=
suffix=
jdcfile=
qflag=
vflag=no
while getopts FVhj:qs:v opt
do
    case "$opt" in
    (F) Fflag="-F";;
    (V) echo "Version information";;
    (h) echo "Help information";;
    (j) jdcfile="$OPTARG";;
    (q) qflag="-q";;
    (s) suffix="$OPTARG";;
    (v) vflag=yes;;
    (*) usage;;
    esac
done

shift $(($OPTIND - 1))

case $# in
(1) : OK;;
(*) usage;;
esac

if [ -z "$jdcfile" ]
then error "you did not specify which jdcfile to use (-j option)"
fi
```

The script then continues and does its task based on the options it was given.  The `shift` removes the 'consumed' options, leaving just the file name arguments.

Comment: #!/bin/bash args=`getopt c:m:p $*` if [ $? != 0 -o $# == 0 ] then echo 'Usage: -c <current-dir> -m <my dir> -p <argument>' exit 1 fi set -- $args for i do case "$i" in -c)   shift;CURRDIR=$1;shift;shift ;; -m) MYDIR=$1;shift;; -p) ARGVAL=$OPTARG;; esac done echo "CURRDIR = $CURRDIR" echo "MYDIR = $MYDIR" echo "ARGVAL = $ARGVAL"

Answer (score 1):

The argument can contain whitespace, so either use the `getopts` built-in shell command or the GNU enhanced version of the external `getopt` program.

The `getopts` option is more portable, because not all systems have the GNU enhanced version of `getopt`. For example, Linux has the GNU enhanced version, but Mac OS X does not. The original version of `getopt` does not support whitespaces.  Despite this limitation, there is a reason why you might want to use toe the GNU enhanced version: it supports long option names, which `getopts` does not.

This is how to use the GNU enhanced `getopt` with whitespaces. It is important to use `"$@"` (use $@ instead of $* and make sure the double quotes are around it) and to `eval` the whole `set` command so that whitespaces are handled properly.

```
eval set -- `getopt --long currdir:,dir:,argval:,verbose -o c:d:k:v -- "$@"`
while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
    case "$1" in
    -c | --currdir)  CURRDIR="$2"; shift;;
    -d | --dir)      MYDIR="$2"; shift;;
    -k | --argval)   ARGVAL="$2"; shift;;
    -v | --verbose)  VERBOSE=yes;;
    esac
    shift
done
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a command `getopts`, and a program `getopt`, though I'm of the opinion that by the time you need to handle arguments, you've outgrown shell scripting.

I'm not actually sure how `getopts` work, having never actually used it; but [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial), and check your shell's docs.

`getopt` splits your arguments into flags -- rest as far as I can tell.

Comment: Using `getopt` is prone to problems with spaces in the arguments - basically, it does not handle them accurately.   The built-in `getopts` does handle spaces in arguments correctly.